# Visual studio c++ Unable to read the project file

Tags: c++

So I just got the Visual Studio 2015 Express installed and tried to make a c++ console application. But it kept give me this error:

[image: Unable to read the project file]

What should I do now?

Comment: I think you should do what the error message tells you:
`"Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk"`.  If the file is not in the proper directory, is it *anywhere* on your drive?

Comment: You skipped step #1 : What is the path in the Import statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.